# HashSet add(Object o) error

Tags: java, generics, hashset

I'm trying to initialize an array of HashSets as follows and it's throwing "no suitable method found for add(Integer)", I tried plainly adding pre[i][0], that didn't work either.

Also, pre is type int[][], numCourses is type int, pre[i][j] is element of [0,numCourses-1].

```
Set<?>[] adj= new HashSet<?>[numCourses];
for(int i=0; i<numCourses; ++i) adj[i]=new HashSet<Integer>();
for(int i=0; i<numCourses; ++i){
    adj[pre[i][1]].add(new Integer(pre[i][0]));
}
```

Could someone help point out what I might be doing wrong?
Further, its not best practice to use wildcard i.e. Set declaration as it loses type-checking ability, any better way to do the above?

Comment: that gives a generic array initialization compile error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer the question of what is directly wrong in your code, `adj[pre[i][1]]` has type `HashSet<?>`, i.e. a HashSet of an *unknown* component type. You cannot add anything (other than `null`) into a such a type, because there is no way to guarantee that whatever you are adding is an instance of this unknown type.

Answer (score 2):

Here's one way to do it :

```
Set<Integer>[] adj = (Set<Integer>[]) new HashSet[numCourses];
for(int i=0; i<numCourses; ++i) adj[i]=new HashSet<Integer>();
for(int i=0; i<numCourses; ++i){
    adj[pre[i][1]].add(new Integer(pre[i][0]));
}
```